# WAITFOR Delay/Time not working properly in Windows Docker (SQL Server Linux)

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu-18.04, docker-for-windows, sql-server-linux

The time specified in the waitfor delay is not honored in SQL Server Linux on Docker Desktop for Windows.

Script:

```sql
declare @tsstart varchar(100) = CONVERT (VARCHAR(100) , SYSDATETIME() ,121);
raiserror(@tsstart,0,0) with nowait;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15';
declare @tend varchar(100)  = CONVERT (VARCHAR(100) ,SYSDATETIME(),121 );
raiserror(@tend,0,0) with nowait;
```

Output:

```
2021-03-25 23:05:23.4457947
2021-03-25 23:05:33.0387152
```

I would expect the @tend would be 2021-03-25 23:05:38.4457947 (because i specified 15 seconds in my waitfor.

The same code executes fine on a SQL Server installed on Windows 10 Pro (laptop). Anything I am missing?

Environment :
SQL Server Linux (2019)

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU9) (KB5000642) - 15.0.4102.2 (X64) 
    Jan 25 2021 20:16:12 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) <X64>
```

Docker for Desktop Windows (Linux Container) (Docker engine: v20.10.5)
[image: Docker Version]

Comment: Is this repeatable in your instance?   I tested on mine  - SQL on Linux in Docker container and I only had millisecond differences. I have the same Docker version and SQL version as you. I have tested about 10 times and cannot repeat your results

Comment: @MartinCairney , yes it is repeatable, even after a restart (of both Docker Desktop and my laptop, the host)

Comment: The difference becomes bigger with bigger WAITFOR values. For 10 seconds delay, it goes to next step in 7 (delta = 3); for a 15 second delay, it goes to next statement in 10 seconds (delta=5)

Comment: Seeing as how it's SQL Server 2019, does `select * from sys.sql_feature_restrictions where feature='WaitFor'` return anything? I would expect no delay if that were active, though.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning , Invalid object name 'sys.sql_feature_restrictions'. is what i get